# How to use pointers to manipulate bits of a particular register in memory using embedded C

Tags: c, embedded

I want to set a 5th bit of a register called RCGCGPIO in RISC uC and I am using pointer dereference method along with bitwise OR operator to directly modify the address of the register that is at 0x40004000. But after executing the program in debugger, there is no change happening at this address. How should I use the pointer arithmetic with bitwise operator?

Refer the code snippet provided. When I use temporary variable to load, modify and store back the data to memory, it works fine. But when I directly use the bit wise operator, then I face this issue

```
#define RCGCGPIO       (*((volatile unsigned short *)0x40004000))
#define N 5
int main(){
    /*To set Nth bit*/
    SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R = SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R | (1U >> N);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: substitute `1U >> N` for `1U << (N - 1)`. Do you use LSB bit ordering?

Comment: wrong usage of shift operator was the issue. SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R |= (1U << (N)); solves the issue

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1U >> N` shifts 1 **right** N bits, meaning it divides 1 by 2<sup>N</sup>. For any N greater than zero, this produces zero.

You likely want `1U << N` to shift **left** N bits, which multiplies by 2<sup>N</sup>.

Comment: wrong usage of shift operator was the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Expression `(1U >> N)` will yield `0` for any `N > 0`, since you use right-shift instead of left-shift. I suppose you count the bit from `1..5`, so the expression should be...

```
SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R |= (1U << (N-1));
```

Comment: wrong usage of shift operator was the issue. Thanks